# Inject form request from modal to another html

Tags: jquery, html, frame, bootstrap-modal

Im making a simple example using Bootstrap and JQuery. I have next code html:

```
<div id="uriModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">URL</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="uri1" class="control-label">URL:</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" id="uri1" placeholder="www.ejemplo.com">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Visualizar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And that is the javascript code:

```
$(function(){

$(document).on("change", "#myForm input", function() {
    if($('#col').is(':checked')) { 
        $("#uriModal").modal();
        console.log($("#uriModal").submit())
        //window.location = $('[name="radio"]:checked').data('url') 
    }
});

});
```

What I want with the form of the modal is saving the request (URI Textbox), to redirect antoher html like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Frame1</title>
</head>
<frameset cols="100%" border="0" frameborder="0" bordercolor="black">
    <frame src="">
</frameset>
</html>
```

On the "frame" element, i want to put the requested URI by the user on the "src" attribute to show on the frame.
How can I do that? Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: ugh, Frames are so 90s..

Comment: Do you want to redirect to a new page? Or exchange to content of the current page? Because the only way to do a redirect with JS ist `window.location.href=<new URL>`. And that will require some server side code create what you asked for. Why don't you change to AJAX result to return a URL for the frame page?

Comment: I want to redirect to this page and changing dynamically the "src" attribute from "frame" element with the URI user puts on the modal form just before.

Comment: If there are alternative instead of use frame, I'm glad to help me

Comment: As I said before, that doesn't work. Javascript from one page has no access to other pages.

Comment: What's the alternative I have to do something similar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92227/discussion-between-jaime-menendez-llana-and-nfechner).